# Error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, refit

**Hello, I am learning to use Refit and I have a problem.**

these are the models

```
public partial class Source
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Article
    {
        [JsonProperty("source")]
        public Source Source { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("author")]
        public string Author { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("url")]
        public Uri Url { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("urlToImage")]
        public Uri UrlToImage { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("publishedAt")]
        public DateTimeOffset PublishedAt { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("content")]
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the interface with the request and its parameters.

```
    public interface IRest
    {
        [Get("/v2/top-headlines")]
        Task<List<Article>> GetArticles(string country, string apiKey"RemovingKey");
    }
```

This is the Request in the ArticleViewModel

```
        private  async Task GetTaskAsync()
        {
            var WeApp = RestService.For<IRest>("https://newsapi.org/");
            var result = await WeApp.GetArticles("co");
        }
```

When I debug to see the data this comes out

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException
  Message=Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) 
into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RefitNpt.Models.Article]'
 because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array 
(e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
 .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) 
that can be deserialized from a JSON object. 
JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'status', line 1, position 10.
```

I've been looking for solutions but I haven't been able to solve them, I'm learning independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another class that will serve as the RootObject for your json response.

```
public class Articles
{
  public string status {get; set;}
  public int totalResults {get;set;}
  public List<Article> articles {get;set; }
}
```

and then use this in your IRest controller, (You will need to update your method (`GetArticles`) to return `Articles` instead of `List<Article>` as well.

```
Task<Articles> GetArticles(string country, string apiKey);
```

This response is aligned with following json snippet that comes from the site `https://newsapi.org`

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "totalResults": 3152,
  "articles": [
    {
      "source": {
        "id": null,
        "name": "Business 2 Community"
      },
      "author": "Gurbaj Singh",
      "title": "Investing in Cryptocurrency? What are the Odds!?",
      "description": "Cryptocurrency has become the most profitable object for investing money. At the same time, in comparison with precious metals, natural…",
      "url": "https://www.business2community.com/finance/investing-in-cryptocurrency-what-are-the-odds-02326876",
      "urlToImage": "https://cdn.business2community.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Untitled-design-3.png",
      "publishedAt": "2020-07-13T15:30:31Z",
      "content": "Cryptocurrency has become the most profitable object for investing money. At the same time, in comparison with precious metals, natural resources, or real estate, virtual coins involve more risks ass… [+9899 chars]"
    },
    // More Articles here...
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your solution helped me to solve this problem, I thank you very much